# Prove $C := \{ x \in \mathbb R^n \mid \|x-c\| \leq a^T x + b \}$ is a convex set

Tags: convex-analysis

> Prove $$C := \{ x \in \mathbb R^n \mid \|x-c\| \leq a^T x + b \}$$ is a convex set.

I was trying to use the definition of a convex set, choosing two vectors in the set and getting two inequalities. But when I was trying to combine them, it came out with a constant term that cannot be canceled. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is the function $x \mapsto \|x-c\| -a^T x -b$ a convex function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\varphi(x)=\|x-c\|-a^{T}x-b$, then 
\begin{align*}
\varphi(tx+(1-t)y)&=\|tx+(1-t)y-c\|-a^{T}(tx+(1-t)y)-b\\
&=\|t(x-c)+(1-t)(y-c)\|-a^{T}(tx+(1-t)y)-tb-(1-t)b\\
&\leq\|t(x-c)\|+\|(1-t)(y-c)\|+t(-a^{T}x-b)+(1-t)(-a^{T}y-b)\\
&=t(\|x-c\|-a^{T}x-b)+(1-t)(\|y-c\|-a^{T}y-b)\\
&=t\varphi(x)+(1-t)\varphi(y).
\end{align*}